# Error en extension Chrome. APIs o codigo?

Tags: javascript, json, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy creando una extensión para mí, para poder agregar billeteras Ethereum o BNB y ver sus saldos. Pero al momento de poner la billetera y apretar "Agregar", me saltan errores que ya no se como solucionarlos.

[image: La extensión y agregado de billetera]

Al principio me saltaba error de API, luego no me salto más, pero ahora me saltan estos dos errores:

[image: Errores]

Dejo el JSON completo:

```
    const walletForm = document.getElementById("walletForm");
    const walletAddress = document.getElementById("walletAddress");
    const totalBalance = document.getElementById("totalBalance");
    const walletList = document.getElementById("walletList");
    
    walletForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const address = walletAddress.value.trim();
    
      if (address) {
        addWallet(address);
      }
    
      walletAddress.value = "";
    });
    
    const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = "FAKEAPI";
    const BSCSCAN_API_KEY = "FAKEAPI";
    
    async function addWallet(address) {
      try {
        const ethereumBalance = await getEthereumBalance(address);
        const bnbBalance = await getBNBBalance(address);
        // Resto del código para agregar la billetera
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error en la función addWallet: \${error.message}`);
      }
    }
    
    async function getEthereumBalance(address) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=\${address}&tag=latest&apikey=FAKEAPI`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Error en la respuesta de la API: \${response.statusText}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.message === 'OK') {
          console.log(`Resultado de la llamada de API: \${data.result}`);
          return BigInt(data.result);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Error en la respuesta de la API: \${data.message}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error en la función getEthereumBalance: \${error.message}`);
        return null;
      }
    }
    
    async function getBNBBalance(address) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=\${address}&tag=latest&apikey=D96DAB88GRZY5UZ3YFJSZMUVA6E5H8EMU8`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Error en la respuesta de la API: \${response.statusText}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.message === 'OK') {
          console.log(`Resultado de la llamada de API: \${data.result}`);
          return BigInt(data.result);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Error en la respuesta de la API: \${data.message}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error en la función getBNBBalance: \${error.message}`);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Ni siquiera funciona que me diga el Error de la API cuando me marca error con la API..

Comment: El error no se da por el  \ antes del ${} ? Me parece curioso, intente usarlo en TS y me imprime el nombre de la variable dentro del `${ }` pero no el valor.